# Javascript - How to reduce the size when converting an image file to Base64 string data?

Tags: javascript, base64

This code converts the image file to Base64 string data. But I want to reduce the size of the base64 string because the size of the base64 string data I converted is larger than the image file. Is that possible?

```
<input id="inputFileToLoad" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="encodeImageFileAsURL();"/>
<div id="imgTest"></div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function encodeImageFileAsURL(){
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files;
    var fileSize = filesSelected[0].size;
    if(fileSize < 10000000){
      if (filesSelected.length > 0){
        var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function (fileLoadedEvent){
          var srcData = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64
          var newImage = document.createElement('img');
          newImage.src = srcData;

          document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;
          alert("Converted Base64 version is " + document.getElementById("imgTest").innerHTML);
        }
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
      }

    } else {
      alert("File exceeded"); 
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No, it's not. By its nature base 64 encoding increases the size by about ~1/3. It is impossible to represent the original data with *less* information if you base 64 encode it. If you want less, you want some sort of compression algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

64 is 2^6(6 bits). This means that every char(8 bits) contains only 6 bits of information. So in order to convey the same amount of information base64 requires 33.3% more bits compared to binary.

The only thing you can do is reduce the size of the original image before you apply base64, this will reduce the size of the base64 string by the same ratio.